# If $f'$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$, then is $f$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

> Say $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable.
>
> Show if $f'$ is bounded, then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

---

**Try**

For any $[a, b] \subset \mathbb{R}$$(a<b)$, I can show $f$ is uniformly continuous, as follows.

> Say $x_0 \in [a,b]$ is given. Fix $\epsilon >0$.
>
> Since $\exists M >0$ s.t. $|f'(x)| \le M$, we show $|y - x_0| < \epsilon/M \Rightarrow |f(y) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.
>
> Assume $\exists y_0 \in [a,b]$ s.t. $|y_0 - x_0| < \epsilon/M$ and $|f(y_0) - f(x_0)| \ge \epsilon$.
>
> Since $\frac{f(y_0) - f(x_0)}{y_0 - x_0} > \epsilon \times M/\epsilon = M$, by MVT $\exists c \in \left[\min\{x_0, y_0\} \max\{x_0, y_0\}\right]$ s.t. $f'(c) = \frac{f(y_0) - f(x_0)}{y_0 - x_0}$. Observe $|f'(c)| > M$, which is a contradiction to $|f'(x)| \le M$.

But I'm not sure I can generalize this fact on $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Moreblue.f' bounded implies f Lipschitz continuous implies f uniformly continuous.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**hint**

$f$ is differentiable at $\Bbb R$ thus by MVT, for all $x,y$, there exists $c$ in $\Bbb R$ such that

$$f(x)-f(y)=(x-y)f'(c)$$ 
but $f'$ is bounded, so

there exist $K> 0$ :
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le K|x-y|.$$

you can take $\eta=\frac{\epsilon}{K}$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any trouble to generalize.

If $x,y \in \mathbb R$ the mean-value theorem gives you a point $z$ in between $x$ and $y$ satisfying $$f(x) - f(y) = f'(z)(x-y)$$ so that
$$|f(x) - f(y)| = |f'(z)| |x-y| \le M |x-y|.$$
This holds for *all* $x$ and $y$.

Thus if $\epsilon > 0$ and $|x-y| < \epsilon /M$, then $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.